# How to fetch data from JSON array and show data inside table?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, http

So in database we have jsonChanges: string[] parameter. Json look like ..

`"{"field":"referringPhysician","oldValue":"Medical oncologist","newValue":"Clinical oncologist"}"`

in my case I need to show in my angular component table oldValue and newValue.
This values inside dropdown after editing user automatically saved to database as old and newValue but inside just one string[] parameter.I need somehow extract this values from this array and show them.

1 -- My table

```
    <table class="listing">
            <thead>
              <th class="table-column-min">User Name</th>
              <th class="table-column-min">Modified Date</th>
              <th class="table-column-min">Entity Name</th>
              <th class="table-column-min">Old Value</th>
              <th class="table-column-min">New Value</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
           <tr *ngFor="let at of auditTrailList | paginate: { itemsPerPage: _ITEMS_PER_PAGE, currentPage: crtPage, totalItems: totalItems }"
        [attr.data-row-id]="at.userId">
        <td>{{ at.userName }}</td>
        <td>{{ at.timestamp ? (at.timestamp | date:  CUSTOM_DATE_FORMAT ) :  'Unknown' }}</td>
        <td>{{ at.entityName }}</td>
        <td>TODO: old value</td>
        <td>TODO: new value</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

2 -- My Component

```
    getList(patientId?: number, pageNo?: number) {
       const auditTrailSubscription = 
   this._auditTrailService.getAuditTrailUrl(patientId, pageNo, 
  GridConfig.ITEMS_PER_PAGE)
     .subscribe(
       result => {
          this.getPersonId();
          this.auditTrailList = result.lstRecords;
          this.totalItems = result.recordsCount;
       },
       err => {
        this.handleError(err);
      }
    );

  this.addSubscription("auditTrail", auditTrailSubscription);
}
```

Comment: So what did you try to do and what is gone wrong?

Comment: How does the complete json structure look like?

Comment: @nirscraft     complete - json  `entityId: 10027
entityName: "Primary Diagnosis (pr)"
id: 10
jsonChanges: "{"field":"referringPhysician","oldValue":"Medical oncologist","newValue":"Clinical oncologist"}"
parentEntityId: null
parentEntityName: null
tenantId: 1
timestamp: 1553696043507
userId: 20020
userName: "Clinician.1"`

Comment: @Dimanoid actually I have no idea how to extract data from this json array. I need to grab old and new value from json and show them in my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you have this array you can store in a variable in your component and pass to your html file, like: 
`this.allData={
               "field":"referringPhysician",
               "oldValue":"Medical oncologist",
               "newValue":"Clinical oncologist"
              }`

and in your html you can show like:

```
<td>{{allData.oldValue}}</td>
<td>{{allData.newValue}}</td>
```

Comment: this oldValue and newValue are dynamic. In my json file field is category name oldValue and newValue is dropdown values. I need to implement code inside getlist().subscribe( result { ... } ). This jsonChanges string[] in side of backend. I need to extract dynamic values. By the way I tried your way and tried also inside my method but it throw back undefined oldValue and newValue

Comment: your `result.jsonChanges` value is `"{"field":"referringPhysician","oldValue":"Medical oncologist","newValue":"Clinical oncologist"}"` and is that dynamic or the value of `newValue`, `oldValue` are dynamic ?  can you please show me your result{}?

Comment: actually I misunderstood but I have small issue.So I use   `<td>{{ at.jsonChanges }}</td>`  in my component html and it returns like `{"field":"referringPhysician","oldValue":"Medical oncologist","newValue":"Cardiac surgeon"}`. I need to show oldValue and newValue from this string[]. This jsonChanges property just one line. I have no idea how to use js code inside angular component html file.

Comment: in your component you can write like : `this.allData=JSON.parse(at.jsonChanges);` and in your html you can use it like `<td>{{allData.oldValue}}</td> <td>{{allData.newValue}}</td>`

Comment: I solved issue but I face new issue with returning multiple values. For this I wrote detail question please look at this [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55414487/how-to-return-multiple-result-in-new-line-using-json-parse-in-angular

Comment: if this answer solve your issue then pls accept the answer, I will check your next question