# How to return multiple result in new line using JSON.parse in Angular?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have json file with multiple results.

1 -- Sample one
`jsonChanges: "{"field":"cancerType","oldValue":"Lentigo maligna melanoma","newValue":"Primary malignant melanoma of g canal"}"`

In this case I am succesfully return all values from list

2 -- Sample two multiple values
`jsonChanges: 
"{"field":"date","oldValue":"","newValue":"Tue Mar 26 00:00:00 GMT 2019"},
{"field":"techniqueType","oldValue":"","newValue":"Intralesional"},{"field":"response","oldValue":"","newValue":"Complete Response"}"`

In this case it returns empty.

In my component.ts I am using

```
   getList(patientId?: number, pageNo?: number) {
        const auditTrailSubscription = 
        this._auditTrailService.getAuditTrailUrl(patientId, pageNo, 
        GridConfig.ITEMS_PER_PAGE)
          .subscribe(
           result => {
            try {
              this.totalItems = result.recordsCount;
              this.auditTrailList = result.lstRecords;
              this.auditTrailList.forEach(x => x.jsonChanges = 
          JSON.parse(x.jsonChanges));          
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        },
        err => {
          this.handleError(err);
        }
      );

    this.addSubscription("auditTrail", auditTrailSubscription);
  }
```

In my html I am using

```
   <tr *ngFor="let at of auditTrailList | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 
      _ITEMS_PER_PAGE, currentPage: crtPage, totalItems: totalItems }"
        [attr.data-row-id]="at.userId">
        <td>{{ at.userName }}</td>
        <td>{{ at.timestamp | date:  CUSTOM_DATE_FORMAT  }}</td>
        <td>{{ at.entityName }}</td>
        <td>{{ at.jsonChanges.field }}</td>
        <td>{{ at.jsonChanges.oldValue }}</td>
        <td>{{ at.jsonChanges.newValue }}</td>
      </tr>
```

The page looks like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3DzH.jpg

My question is how to get multiple values and show them in new row.For returning single value it is ok. But for multiple values I have no idea.

Comment: The code in sample (2) is not a valid JSON string. It should be wrapped in an array. You can fix this issue by adding the brackets manually `JSON.parse(\`[${x.jsonChanges}]\`)`; however, I recommend trying to resolve this in the API if it is possible.

Comment: @Gasim  manually I haven’t access to backend. This values are dynamic. I just use my own service (url which is sent by backend). In my case there are 2 tables when user changes some values it automatically saves new data to new table. I am just fetching data from this table. This jsonChanges just simple string not an array. For one line values field>oldvalue>newvalue JSON.parse return values without any problem, but in case of multiple lines it throws syntax error.

Comment: @Gasim unfortunetaly they closed task for backend and I need to figure out on my own. By the way `JSON.parse(`[${x.jsonChanges}]`)` didn't work and returns nothing but does not throw exception in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding additional array and getting results from this array solved my solution.

```
     try {
        this.results = [];
        this.totalItems = result.recordsCount;
        this.auditTrailList = result.lstRecords;
        this.auditTrailList.forEach(x => {
          const jschanges = JSON.parse(`[${x.jsonChanges}]`);
          jschanges.forEach(z => {
            this.results.push({
              userName: x.userName,
              timestamp: x.timestamp,
              entityName: x.entityName,
              field: z.field,
              oldValue: z.oldValue,
              newValue: z.newValue
            })
          })
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code in your component:

```
this.str='{"field":"referringPhysician","oldValue":"Medical oncologist","newValue":"Cardiac surgeon"},{"field":"cancerType","oldValue":"Lentigo maligna melanoma","newValue":"Primary malignant melanoma of g canal"}';
this.arrData=this.str.split('},');
this.arrData.forEach((val, key) => {
  if(key != this.arrData.length-1){
    this.allData.push(JSON.parse(val+'}'));
  }else{
    this.allData.push(JSON.parse(val));
  }
});
console.log(this.allData);
```

then you have to user *ngFor in your html file

Comment: I tried , but unfortunately it still returns empty.

Comment: In my this code show (in console): `0: {field: "referringPhysician", oldValue: "Medical oncologist", newValue: "Cardiac surgeon"}
1: {field: "cancerType", oldValue: "Lentigo maligna melanoma", newValue: "Primary malignant melanoma of g canal"}`.  can you please show your code where you implement my example one?

Comment: I can't cause of too long code. But I used your approach. Actually this.str it is not static value like this. I get json from db. And this json in format string. For return single line changes like just 1 field => oldValue & newValue it works. For multiple cases don't

Comment: yes, `this.str` is a static one for your understand. you can put your string into `this.str` whice string json is come from your DB, and see your console for testing.

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 72
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at :4200/app-pages-common-cancer-elements-common-cancer-elements-module.06f46a405fcca172e09f.js:52687
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)` error I understand but I have no idea fetch multiple data from string and show it seperately in new line. But again thanks for your help.

Comment: this is `SyntaxError` , may be your make some mistake inside `JSON.parse` when you call. can you show me only that part where you use my approach

Comment: `if (key !=this.arrData.length - 1) {
this.auditTrailList.push(JSON.parse(val + '}'));` throws error in this line

Comment: Interesting part is it works with single line but does not works with multiple

Comment: you have two `forEach` loop running, one is `auditTrailList` (this one is main one) another one inside this  call `arrData`, isn't it? if yes then you push again inside of `auditTrailList` looping

Comment: single line work because `JSON.parse()` can parse but multiple one does not works because `JSON.parse()` does not understand your string, thats why I `split()` and make it understandable for `JSON.parse()`

Comment: but when you use `split()` it return an array, for that reason you have to use another loop

Comment: problem is jsonChanges property just string property not an array. In our case split does not work because it returns array as you said.But I need just take data from one string

Comment: yes i know your `jsonChanges` is string and for that i made this approach. why you cannot use my approach inside of your loop like: `this.auditTrailList.forEach((v,k) =>{this.str=v.jsonChanges;..........................});`

Comment: As I mentioned I used your approach but unfortunately it still returns empty.

Comment: I don't understand if your `jsonChanges` look like my `this.str` why it doesn't work, because i found right array in my console. can you please debug little by little, and part by part. first give print your `jsonChanges` in console and see, if right then `this.arrData`, if right then `this.allData`